# product_tag to style an image

Tags: plugins

I want to style my product images depending on product tags (not only the first tag, but all of them).

I am using this:

```
<img class="<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->id, 'product_tag'); ?>"
```

and it is not working, because Woocommerce/Wordpress is styling the product tags as a link.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try looking to see if there is css that is causing this issue. Then your code might work. This may just be a specificity issue in your css.